# Statusbar orientation changes after dismissing modal view

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

My statusbar orientation is landscape, I have a cocos2d view that only supports portrait orientation(it is OK since it handles transformations). I have another view that is presented as a modal by cocos2d controller, its orientation is landscape, but whenever I dismiss it, my statusbar orientation somehow changes to portrait, I tried overriding supported orientation methods of container views, but none of them has any effect.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is how I did it, I thought what messes things up is the fact that orientation of container being different from the view that is presented as modal. So I added another view to contain cocos2d view and presented the modal using that view. The container's orientation is lanscape, so I needed to transform cocos2d view int he load method of its controller.

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view.transform, -(M_PI / 2.0));
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
```

I am still looking for a better way of doing this.